# Scheduled Recurring Crystal Reports runs with delay

Tags: scheduler, crystal-reports-2008, business-objects

Suddenly all the scheduled reports runs with a delay of one hour.
Does this have anything to do with daylight savings?
The environment is: Crystal Report Server 2008, Tomcat and Business Objects Enterprise 12.0

Detail: This started to happen last weekend,when the Brazilian daylight saving was supposed to end. The server wrongly adjusted the time to end of the daylight saving.
(Here the dates of daylight savings are not default (E.g: Starts third Saturday of October, ends second Saturday of February). Due to politics reason this changes every year).

Anyway, we set the timezone again to daylight saving (which actually is going to end February 17 - this weekend). Restarted the server, but on Crystal Management Console all the reports are wrongly scheduled with +1hour. (E.g: If the report is supposed to be delivered at 12:00 PM, it's doing on 1:00 PM)

Has anyone came across this issue? I did not find anything relevant to my problem on web researches; is there a workaround for this issue? Any time zone configuration that should be made (where?) ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What operating system are you using? Windows Server version?

Comment: Windows Server 2003 R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the timezone ended, the schedulling reports runned on the right time again. Crystal Server had a delay in adjusting the time,because it does only when the server is idle.